# How to get tooltip to show when mousing over a ToolStripStatusLabel?

Tags: winforms

I want to show a filename on my status strip, and the full path when the user mouses over it. Here's what I've done:

```
lblFileName.Text = fi.Name;
lblFileName.ToolTipText = fi.FullName;
```

But when I mouse over it, the tool tip text never shows up. How come?

[image]

(Mousing over "waterfall.png" does nothing)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Forcing a guess, I'd say that you forgot to set the StatusStrip's `ShowItemToolTips` to `True`.

Comment: Yessir! Didn't think to look at the strip's properties.